# How to add an image after the dynamic label?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I had an application in which i am adding an image after the label,the label is dynamic. I need to add an image after that `UILabel`. I tried  `

```
 dropdownlabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [dropdownlabel setFrame:CGRectMake(90,8,180, 30)];
    [dropdownlabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]];
    dropdownlabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    dropdownlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dropdownlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    dropdownlabel.text=@"gdhhgsfghdfagsfd ";

    dropdownlabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
   [navview addSubview:dropdownlabel];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(9999,30);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [dropdownlabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:dropdownlabel.lineBreakMode]; 

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = dropdownlabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    dropdownlabel.frame = newFrame;


    NSLog(@"%f",newFrame.size.width);
    UIImageView *navview1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( newFrame.size.width+15,13,20,20)];
    navview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down_sml_arrow.png"];
    navview1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [navview addSubview:navview1];
```

But for some it is correct, but for another it is wrong. Can anybody guide me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You should also consider label's origin X with width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dropdownlabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[dropdownlabel setFrame:CGRectMake(90,8,180, 30)];
[dropdownlabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]];
dropdownlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
dropdownlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
dropdownlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
dropdownlabel.text=@"gdhhgsfghdfagsfd ";

dropdownlabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[navview addSubview:dropdownlabel];

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [dropdownlabel.text sizeWithFont:dropdownlabel.font];

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = dropdownlabel.frame;
newFrame.size = expectedLabelSize;
dropdownlabel.frame = newFrame;


UIImageView *navview1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x+newFrame.size.width+15,13,20,20)];
navview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down_sml_arrow.png"];
navview1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[navview addSubview:navview1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just taking the width of the labels frame as your `origin.x` value for your imageView. Instead you also have to consider the origin value of your label. User `CGRectGetMaxX(newFrame) + 15`  for the origin of your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

WhenEver Your `UILabel` Is created Each Time you got its Size of your label, So you also Got **UILabel's 'X', 'Y' and 'Height'**. It is Helpful for Add Image after Created `UILabel`.
YOu also need to Add Dynamic `UIImageView` as `UILabel` for add Images.

How To give Fram of `UIImageView` after Added `UILabel`, For Example.

your `UILabel` sise is,

```
myLabel.fram = CGRectMake(10, 290, 200, 50);

MyLabel.fram.origin.x = 10;
MyLabel.fram.origin.y = 290;
MyLabel.fram.size.width = 200;
MyLabel.fram.size.height = 50;
```

so, I give fram of `UIImageView` base on `myLabel's` Fram;

```
myImageView.fram = CGRectMake(MyLabel.fram.origin.x, MyLabel.fram.origin.y + MyLabel.fram.size.height , 200, 50); /// Here you can also set width and height as you need (similar to UILabel also)
```

Comment: Your first answer doesnt suite your reputation

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are changing the width of the label dynamically.

```
 UIImageView *navview1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(dropdownlabel.frame.origin.x+dropdownlabel.frame.size.width+15 ,13,20,20)];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider label's origin X with width

```
UIImageView *navview1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x+newFrame.size.width+5,13,20,20)];
navview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down_sml_arrow.png"];
navview1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[navview addSubview:navview1];
```